# change divs background on click of radio button

Tags: jquery

I have 4 radio buttons, each is enclosed in a div seperately.
In jQuery, I want to click a radio button and have the color of related div change.
When I click 2nd radio button, the previous div's color should restored and the 
newlyclicked radio buttons div color should changed.
when i click a radio butoon all divs colors changed i want only 
selected to be changed

```
$('input:[name=pid]:radio').click(function () {
$(".column-title").css("background", "gray"); 

 below is the html of one div.
 <th><h3 class="column-title" style="height:60px; width:130px; background:#999; border-top-left-radius:10px;border-top-right-radius:10px; margin:0px; padding-top: 13px;">
<div style="color:#FFF; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:15px;"><?=$arr['Deluxe']['title']?></div>
</h3>

<div style="font-size:19px; float:left;padding: 27px 0 0; margin:0px;width:129px; border-right:1px solid #999">
<input type="radio" value="<?=($arr['Deluxe']['id'])?>" name="pid" Checked/>

<div class="new"><?php echo $arr['Deluxe']['price'].'/mon'; ?></div>

<div style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;">after your trial</div>

</div>
</th>
```

Comment: If you want only selected to be changed you should use like this `$('input[name=pid]:radio:selected').click(function(){ // do something});`-- it gives the selected one

Comment: Duplicate question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764887/one-div-with-background-color-999-in-it-another-div-with-input-button/14765049#14765049)

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

**CSS**

```
.highlight{
background-color:'yellow';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="rdb-container">
<input type="radio" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="rdb-container">
<input type="radio" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="rdb-container">
<input type="radio" value="3" />
</div>
<div class="rdb-container">
<input type="radio" value="4" />
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('div.rdb-container input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    $('div.rdb-container').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).parent('div.rdb-container:first').addClass('highlight');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=pid]').change(function () {
```

That being said you can add a class to the div elements, decalre a CSS class and use `closest` method.

```
.active { background-color: 'red'}
```

```
$(function() {
   var $divs = $('div.mydivs');

   $('input[type="radio"][name="pid"]').change(function () {
      $divs.removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('div.mydiv').addClass('active');
   })
})
```